# Flash player "now playing list" without interrupting current song

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, flash

I am designing a website that plays music. I need a flash player that has or can handle a now playing list. The problem I am facing is that I cannot update the playlist without refreshing the player which means it will interrupt the song that is currently playing. I have trying with JW player in particular so far and have not been successful. All i am able to do is pass a playlist as an xml file but not able to update it without refreshing the playlist.
Is there any other player that would better suit my needs? Is there a way i can do this with jw player itself

Comment: Did you already try what is suggest here: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forum/JavaScript-Interaction/15681/How-to-Show-Now-Playing-URL

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/ehonu/20

Ok. here we go..!

First of, **[here](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/contributors/nyboe/JW_API_xmpl_6-2-0-0.html)** there is a **Must Read** from the JW official site! and here the **[events doc](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/Player4Events#Viewevents)**

Anyway, my way is by using COOKIES & [JW Player: ActionScript API Calls](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/Player5Api)

the idea behind, is that since jw player can use **Listeners** and theese can Listen also the **Curent Position** of the song in this moment, **we track** it into **coockie** when Page **UNLOAD**

then it can also **SEND EVENTS** so when page refresh and dom is loaded we send back the position to the player! ;-)

for the Refreshing Playlist without refresh Page you can of course use the Send Event like this:

```
setTimeout("refreshPlaylist('myfile.xml')",2000);

function refreshPlaylist(theFile) { 
currentItem = -1; 
previousItem = -1; 
//this Reload the playlist
player.sendEvent('LOAD', theFile); 
};​
```

For better Understand Look Into the code of demo example!

Let me know!

Comment: already saw that...the links that explain how to exactly to that dont work anymore :(

Comment: hello. THe demo site doesnt seem to work for me. The player doesn't load. Thanks for the code anyway.... i'm having a look at it now

Comment: I know! ;-) the Demo could not work cause of jsbin server but try to upload the script on your own server! Let me know!